# How Do I Write This IN Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
video_id  tag_id
10        7
6         7
10        5
6         5
9         5
9         4
10        4
```

I want to write a query which will give me `video_id` which have both `tag_id` 7 and 5. So `video_id` 10 and 6 should be selected, but not 9.

I tried `where tag_id IN (7, 5)` condition but obviously that includes 9.

Comment: Please tag your question with the SQL DBMS you're using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.), since the correct syntax and recommendations depends on it.

Comment: Use a search engine to research `relational division`. That will also help you to decide if you want videos that *only* have tags 7 and 5, or have 7, 5, and possibly others

Comment: @Barmar tagged mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work for you?

```
SELECT video_id
FROM table1
WHERE tag_id iN (7,5)
GROUP BY video_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) =2;
```

**Update**.
If you have a unique constraint on (video_id,tag_id), no need for `COUNT(DISTINCT)`; `COUNT(*)` will work as well

Comment: HAVING and GROUP BY conflicts.

Comment: @Salman : it shouldn't; I just tried on Mysql and SQLServer. Did you try the query as it is now? I made couple updates (fixing misprints)

Comment: The query looks OK to me too. However it is only working if I omit the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: it sounds strange... what RDMS?

Comment: mysql. I didn't add the tag earlier.

Comment: Actually it worked. I made a mistake putting `HAVING` before 'GROUP BY'.

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrary solution -

Below is an answer for sql server, with mysql you would need a count() on video_id and then look for rows with the value needed.

I don't have mysql to test but feel free to add an edit of a correct mysql solution.

---

With a table called neededtag with one column (tag) that has the list of what you want

```
SELECT video_id
FROM
(
  SELECT video_id, 
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY vidio_id ORDER BY video_ID) as RN
  FROM table
  JOIN neededtag ON tag_id = tag
) sub
WHERE RN = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM neededtag)
```

or maybe your needed tag has a criteraname column... then it would look like this:

```
SELECT video_id
FROM
(
  SELECT video_id, 
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY vidio_id ORDER BY video_ID) as RN
  FROM table
  JOIN neededtag ON tag_id = tag and criteraname = "friday tag list"
) sub
WHERE RN = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM neededtag WHERE criteraname = "friday tag list")
```

---

Prior answer

```
SELECT video_id
FROM table
WHERE tag_id = 5
INTERSECT
SELECT video_id
FROM table
WHERE tag_id = 7
```

or

```
SELECT video_id
FROM table
WHERE tag_id = 5
AND video_id IN 
(
  SELECT video_id
  FROM table
  WHERE tag_id = 7
)
```

or

```
SELECT v1.video_id
FROM table v1
JOIN table v2 WHERE v1.video_id = v2.video_id AND v2.tag_id = 7
WHERE tag_id = 5
```

Comment: I haven't checked if the second one works, but it will be problematic when I try to select for 3 or more tags.

Comment: @Salman - selecting for 3 or more tags was not in your question -- is that what you want... arbitrary number of requirements?

Comment: UNION is incorrect because it returns videos with either tag, not the ones with both tags. It's the same as the query the OP tried.

Comment: Your latest update uses SQL features that MySQL doesn't support: ROW_NUMBER(), OVER, PARTITION.

Comment: @Barmar you are right -- also, the MySQL was added after I read the question.

Answer (score 0):

There may be faster ways to do it, but this is straightforward.  I'm assuming there's a videos table with primary key video_id, so I don't have to SELECT DISTINCT.

```
SELECT v.video_id FROM videos as v WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tagtable as t WHERE t.video_id = v.video_id and tag_id = 7)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tagtable as t WHERE t.video_id = v.video_id and tag_id = 5)
```